# How to remove Google Software Update from Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I briefly installed Chrome on OSX Mavericks. I decided to delete Chrome.

My user account "manages" web browsing for me, so only websites authorised by me are allowed access. I do this so I can keep track of which websites software installed on my Mac are really accessing.

To my surprise, "Google Software Update" seems to be installed on my Mac, and is trying to connect to google analytics. I deleted Chrome, so I don't see why this should be installed.

Using Finder, I can't find any "Google" software using the search feature.

How can I remove this ?

Comment: More seriously, according to [this page](http://raamdev.com/2008/howto-remove-google-software-update-on-mac-os-x/), the command to do it is `sudo /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py --uninstall`

Comment: I have the directory `~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resour‌​ces/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/`, but it doesn't contain `install.py`. What should I do?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: checkmy answer below, I have stated what is the new command.

Comment: This seems to be very version-specific, so people answering or commenting on this, please state whether your comment applies to 10.8, 10.9 or 10.10

Comment: According to the [Google Updater for the Mac FAQs page](https://tools.google.com/mac/updaterfaq.html), “Google Updater for Mac has been retired”. I think that means after you uninstall it once, it won’t be reinstalled – you don’t have to lock folders or anything to prevent it from coming back.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Google Updater certainly doesn't seem like it's "retired" as of January 2023 — I just bought a new Macbook a month ago, started using it with a clean install, and I somehow have Google Updater somehow on my machine. Worse: since I disabled it on my Login Items, it gives me a notification every single time my Mac starts or wakes from sleep. I'm trying to find out how to get rid of it…

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The new command is now the following:

```
sudo ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Helpers/ksinstall --uninstall
```

These were older commands/paths:

```
sudo ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resour‌​ces/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/ksinstall --uninstall
sudo /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py --nuke
```

In the older command above, you may prefer to replace the `--uninstall` with the `--nuke` option. The former supposedly leaves some files, while the latter removes them.

Alternatively, Google Software Update might be installed within `/Library/`, in which case it can be removed with:

```
sudo /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/ksinstall --uninstall
```

Also try:

```
sudo /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Helpers/ksinstall --uninstall
```

Comment: As of OS X Yosemite 10.10.2, this does not work. Google must have renamed something.

Comment: Why the downvote? I have reinstalled Yosemite 10.10.2 last week and I still haven't redone the process. So now I have just tried the uninstall process and it's still working!! So please, try again, this time type the command instead of copy/pasting it, and upvote again, because it IS working! I'm using Chrome 41, and to test it, just do "About Chrome" and update process will fail.

Comment: Henrique - I did not down vote you. I simply left my comment there for future searches. I have already uninstalled Chrome. But before I did, there was no kinstall program. I guess our two systems are just different. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I did reinstall Yosemite 10.10.2 a week ago and installed Chrome 41 Stable Release. If you wish, you can find the kinstall by performing the following command: `find / -name kinstall`

Comment: It seems as though google renamed the file to ```ksinstall``` .

Comment: worked for me, but you need to take care just copy pasting it, on my system it just added a few spaces in the path. Changed `/Resources/` to `/Resou   rces/`

Comment: `command not found`

Comment: I just confirmed this xmas eve, and it *is* working!

Comment: This is correct for Mac OSX 10.11.2. Use the --nuke option instead of --install to get rid of everything. Then remove the ~/Library/Google directory.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you continue to use Chrome, GoogleSoftwareUpdate will just reinstall itself.  I use Chrome but wanted it without the spyware.  Guess that's not possible

Comment: I woke up today and my Mac was shutdown.  This was the second time in a few days.  The last thing in the system log was GoogleSoftwareUpdate.  So I did: /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/ksinstall --nuke.  I'm on 10.12 (Sierra).  I shutdown and rebooted.  Things appear fine.

Comment: Run `touch ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate && sudo chown -R root:wheel ~/Library/Google` after running the `--nuke` command above.  This replaces the updater directory with a file and locks your user out of it, which will now prevent Chrome bringing it back.  The `chown` might be overkill, but it does give good assurance nothing is messing with that file.

Comment: Oddly enough, copy-pasting the command didn't work for me. But dragging the ksinstall file in the terminal worked, even though they appear to be the same path. Could it be some strange invisible ASCII character in the answer?

Comment: New location/script: `sudo /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py --nuke`

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa @jhfrontz  Does this answer need to be edited to have `--nuke` or `--uninstall` in the first line? Right now it ends with `install.py`

Comment: @beroe I don't think there's a definitive answer; which command/options to use seems to be a moving target that depends on the version of various components and the whim of google.

Comment: For me it now lives under `~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Helpers/ksinstall --uninstall`

Answer (score 10):

On [their official help page](https://support.google.com/installer/answer/147176?hl=en), they only mention disabling the checks:

> To disable Google Software Update from checking for updates, execute
>   the following in the Terminal application:
>
> ```
> $ defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0
> ```

Comment: This doesn't disabled the auto update of Chrome on my system. Would be nice to find another working solution without uninstalling update service

Comment: If you go to “About Google Chrome” info window it will still check then, but it shouldn't run automatically anymore in the background.

Comment: but it does. Have you tested on OSX 10.10?

Comment: No, I am running 10.9 only.

Comment: People commenting here, please state whether your comment applies to 10.8, 10.9 or 10.10

Comment: This seems to work with 10.14

Answer (score 9):

Success on a Mac Sept 29, 2017:

The "official" Google-given method given to stop the Google Software Update is this, but it doesn't always work. The updater sometimes, on some systems, finds a way to reset itself and update anyway.
In Terminal: `defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0`

The most foolproof method is to deny Chrome the permissions it needs to install the update software and run it. Empty these directories:
`/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/`
~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/

Then change the permissions on both folders named `GoogleSoftwareUpdate` so that there's no owner and no read/write/execute permissions.

In terminal:

```
cd /Library/Google/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate
sudo chmod 000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate
cd ~/Library/Google/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup GoogleSoftwareUpdate
sudo chmod 000 GoogleSoftwareUpdate
```

If you want to be double-certain, then do the same for the folder Google one level up.

```
cd /Library/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup Google
sudo chmod 000 Google
cd ~/Library/
sudo chown nobody:nogroup Google
sudo chmod 000 Google
```

I did this immediately after installing the Chrome version I need for my machine, and it worked perfectly. Now when I check About Google Chrome it gives me the error "Update failed (error: 10)" It's still trying to update, but it can't do it any more.

Answer (score 7):

Use --help to see the various ksinstall options, i.e. ksinstall --help

```
cd ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resour‌​ces/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/

ksinstall --help

[--install=PKG]     Install keystone using PKG as the source.
[--uninstall]       Remove Keystone program files but do NOT delete
                    the ticket store.
[--nuke]            Remove Keystone and all tickets.
[--interval=N]      Set installed agent to wake up every N seconds.
[--lockdown]        Prevent Keystone from ever uninstalling itself.
[--force]           Perform operation even if it is a downgrade.
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Or `/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/REsources/ksinstall --help` for those with GSU installed system-wide.

Answer (score 4):

In my Mac OS X 10.9.5 ksinstall resides in the main library. The commend is thus:

```
sudo /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/ksinstall --nuke
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually (14 Dec 2020) the binary to manage Google Software Update on OSX is located at:

```
~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Helpers/ksinstall
```

you can use `-h` parameter to see available options or simply use:

```
sudo ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Helpers/ksinstall --nuke
```

to

> Remove Keystone and all tickets

Comment: I use Homebrew to manage Chrome installations. So, I guess I'll need to run this after every Homebrew update of Chrome for it to remain in effect? Thanks for sharing this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my method

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks
touch /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks
sudo chown root:admin /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks
sudo chmod 400 /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks

sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate
touch ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate
sudo chown root:admin ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate
sudo chmod 400 ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate
```

When check for new versions:

```
Update failed (error: 12)

Error details:
KSInstallAction install script failure. Exit code: 5. Standard error output: "mkdir: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions: Not a directory\n.keystone_install: mkdir of installed_versions_dir failed\n".
```