# Why does GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent keep returning?

Tags: google-chrome

I have uninstalled GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent many times with reference to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/730736/how-to-remove-google-software-update-from-mac-osx/1077420) but it keeps coming back. I'm really not sure why. The only thing I can think that may be happening is that it downloads when downloading other software like Filezilla updates. I have removed all the Google files I have found on my computer using  find / google. I must have removed it about 10 times now but it keeps coming back. Is this a virus?

Comment: It absolutely is not a virus. Are you connected to an Active Directory domain by chance?

Comment: It has since come back! I'm on mac so I dont think I have an Active Directory service

Comment: actually i think i might know the answer to this question... im using opera browser which is chromium

Comment: can anyone confirm that it is Opera that is downloading this folder? it keeps coming back and if it's not Opera I dont want it. It downloads to my user library folder on mac